# On Windows 7, how to fix VLC Media volume capped when Firefox plays sound?

Tags: windows-7, audio, vlc-media-player

Using Mixer, I have set the volume of VLC Media player to be even with the master volume, also, this is even with other applications such as Firefox.

But when Firefox plays a sound, I can hear the sound of VLC Media is reduced, and the slider is animated downwards in the mixer (though a faded piece of the slider remains where I specifically set it).

[image]

I would just increase VLC volume to compensate, but then when the next track comes up, its too loud.

Can you tell by this screenshot what is going on? And how do I fix?

Comment: Phone call - I wonder if this has anything to do with Firefox Hello. I don't know for sure because I didn't have VLC for very long before my first Hello call.

Comment: Yes, sounds plausible (pun intended :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Control Panel / Sound / Communications tab` and set it to *Do nothing*:

[image: 1]